Java can't open any .jar files
I was following this tutorial: https://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/ to get started with OpenTripPlanner for the first time. Once I got to the step "starting OTP" I encountered a problem. I typed in "java -jar otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar" into cmd, and it gave back: "Error: Unable to access jarfile otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar". So I started looking online for solutions to this problem, and i've tried every single one I came across, including all of the solutions given in this thread: What causes "Unable to access jarfile" error?, but to no avail. Then I started wondering, can I even open any .jar file at all? So I downloaded this test .jar file: https://github.com/jarirajari/helloworld, and tried opening it but it gave the same error message! So now I'm thinking somehow the Java on my PC just can't open .jar files at all. Is there anything I can try to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

What is your current working directory ?
Make Sure you use the cd command to navigate to the same directory the jar file stored in.

Your on Windows or *nix?

Does dir otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar (Windows) or ls otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar (Mac/Linux) work?

@Ammar My working directory is C:\Windows\System32>. Should it be something else?

@talex I'm working on Windows 11.

@VGR If I try that I get this: C:\Windows\System32>dir otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar
Volume in drive C is Windows
Volume Serial Number is 680F-7BDB
Directory of C:\Windows\System32
File Not Found
Which makes me more confused because it seems like cmd can't find the file at all? Eventhough I can see it sitting in my Downloads folder with that exact name.

@VGR I also tried dir otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar with the directory of C:\Users[my username], and I got the same result.

In all operating systems, programs do not “find” files.  You have to specify the location of the file you want a program to use.  If you don’t specify which directory a file is in, every program will assume it’s in the current working directory.  So, yes, you must change your current working directory to your Downloads directory… or specify the full path, for example java -jar C:\Users\Noah\Downloads\otp-2.5.0-shaded.jar.

If your current directory is C:\Windows\System32, there is a strong likelihood that you are running an elevated cmd.exe window. Don't do that! You clearly do not have the knowledge or experience to determine whether the author of the 'tutorial' is going to compromise your system, and/or, data.

@VGR When I try to open it with the full path specified, I get this: ERROR [main]  (OTPMain.java:92) Parameter error: You must supply a single directory name.

That error seems pretty self-explanatory.  I suggest reading all of the first link in your question.

You have to be in the same directory as the jar file.
Here is how to open a cmd window in a directory.
1- open explorer
2- then navigate to the directory where you have the jar file
3- in the the explorer in the top left text field type cmd.

It will open a new cmd window in the directory currently opened in explorer.
4- execute the jar file in my case I would type java -jar program.jar


I recommend reading more about navigating directories in a shell with cd

Windows 11 explorer should be similar to my window 10 one

Hi, thanks for your answer. If I try to open it this way I get this error message: ERROR [main]  (OTPMain.java:92) Parameter error: You must supply a single directory name.

Well that means it works.
That error is not related to the question.
Your problem was that the program didn't run and now it did run with an error.
read the program documentation to see what parameters it needs :)

Method 1
The current directory in cmd must be the directory where the JAR file is located.
First, you have to check where your JAR file is located.
Use the Windows explorer to browse to the directory where the JAR file is located. Copy or remember the directory.
Now, open the cmd and change to this directory by using the cd "<directory>" command.
For example, if your JAR file is located in C:\MyData\MyProject use:
cd "C:\MyData\MyProject"

The cmd should now show the prompt C:\MyData\MyProject>.
Now you should be able to execute the java -jar <JarFile> command.
Method 2
Alternatively, you can specify the full path of the JAR file in the Java command, for example:
java -jar "C:\MyData\MyProject\MyJarFile.jar"

In this case, the current directory in cmd does not matter.

Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried both methods you mentioned, and with both occasions I get this error message: ERROR [main]  (OTPMain.java:92) Parameter error: You must supply a single directory name.

At this point I can only assume about the issue but it looks like that calling the main method of OTPMain class does require (at least) 1 argument. IMHO this error message comes from the OTPMain class that requires to specify a directory.
Maybe you can check the documentation of the package/JAR file/class or the source code (if available).
You can provide (1 or more) arguments to the Java command by adding them as Strings, for example: java -jar "C:\MyData\MyProject\MyJarFile.jar" "C:\MyData\MyProvidedDir" adds argument C:\MyData\MyProvidedDir to the command.

OMG C:\Windows\System32 is very special directory. Don't use it for anything.
Create new directory in C:\User\[your username] (you need to put your username in brackets) o and use that directory instead.
Also you need to have your jar files in that directory.

Oh. C:\Windows\System32 is what cmd automatically opens in when I run it as administrator, which is what I had been doing the past couple of tries because some people online said that that could help fix the problem. nevertheless, if I try it with the directory of C:\Users[my username], the same error still occurs.

I suggest you to stop using Administrator account willy-nilly, you may accidentally break something. What exact folder name you use now?

What do you mean exactly with "What exact folder name you use now?"?

I mean what is your current directory?
